# VxWorks 6.6 performance

Tags: real-time, vxworks

Im trying to to find vxworks 6.6 characteristics.
I want to know what is the execution time for:

1. Context switch
2. Inter-Process Communication - using queues

I found some interesting work on this issue in "Performance Analysis of VxWorks and RTLinux" article.
But i would like to confirm this information.

Answer (score 2):

No precise answer can be given to your question.
Execution time is directly linked to the hardware on which your application is running.

All benchmark (not only VxWorks) should be given with precise hardware configuration and should be taken as is. You can't infer the performance of a given software on a different hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Now I am using VxWorks 6.7, and I have write some test cases to measure the time of context switch time,you can also create test case.The steps: first create two task(taskA, taskB),and then switch taskA to taskB, you should read the time interval between before switch and after switch.if you use pentium, use pentiumTscGet32() to record time, or you can use oscilloscope. If you want see more details visit the site http://www.segger.com/embos-context-switching-time.html . I hope it will help you.

Comment: Since links often go stale, [it is important](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, it's my first time to answer question, and I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Context switch time is heavily dependent upon the hardware you are executing on.  Each hardware has its own Board Support Package that implements the kernel context switch for that particular system.